# Check 'checkBox' in another way -> xPath

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm using this code:

```
//input[@type='checkbox'][following-sibling::text()[position()=1]][2]
```

for checking boxes, but i want to use string, not number (example: 'Uczyń odpowiedzialnym' instead of [2]).
I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
//input[@type='checkbox'][following-sibling::text()[position()=1][contains(., 'Uczyń odpowiedzialnym')]]
```

HTML code:

```
<input class="prettifiedIeCheckbox ng-pristine ng-valid" type="checkbox" ng-model="holdersModel.OnlyForRead"></input>
<label>
    <span class="bottom">
    Tylko do wglądu
    </span>
</label>
<input class="prettifiedIeCheckbox ng-pristine ng-valid" type="checkbox" ng-model="holdersModel.ChangeMainHolder"></input>
<label>
    <span class="bottom">
    Uczyń odpowiedzialnym
    </span>
</label>
```

@sideshowbarker help ;)

Comment: //label/span[contains(., 'Uczyń odpowiedzialnym')]]

Comment: @ShubhamJain nope, it would locate the `span` element while the OP is looking for a way to locate the `input` element based on the label.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check the `span` element's text in the following `label` sibling node:

```
//input[@type='checkbox' and following-sibling::label/span = 'Uczyń odpowiedzialnym']
```

There are, certainly, other ways to locate the element. For instance, check `ng-model`:

```
//input[contains(@ng-model, 'ChangeMainHolder')]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the below xpath:

```
//span[contains(.,'Uczyn odpowiedzialnym')]/preceding::input[1]
```

This will select the first `input` element that is present before the `span` element with exact innerHTML/text as **Uczyń odpowiedzialnym**.

Answer (score 0):

I found another (better) solution on sqa.stackexchange by @Sam Woods, modified for my problem:

```
IWebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox' and contains(@ng-model, 'ChangeMainHolder')]"));
if (!element.Selected)
{
    element.Click();
}
```